# setTimeout with jQuery.hover() overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, settimeout

I've got an effect I want triggered one second after page load, then subsequently every 3 seconds (on repeat). When the user hovers over an element (**`#hover`**), the effect pauses (temporarily). When they stop hovering over it, the effect resumes after 2 seconds.

I'm having a lot of trouble with overlapping sounds and animations, particularly when I hover and then unhover over the element quickly. What's wrong with my code? ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxbmu/3/))

```
var test;
function hoverTest(arg) {
  if (arg == 'stop') {
    clearTimeout(test);
  }
  if (arg == 'start') {
    playSound();
    $('#hover').transition({
      opacity: 0,
      duration: 1000,
      complete: function() {
        $('#hover').transition({
          opacity: 1,
          duration: 1000,
          complete: function() {
            test = setTimeout(function() { hoverTest('start'); }, 3000);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}

$('#hover').hover(function() {
  hoverTest('stop');
}, function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    hoverTest('start');
  }, 2000);
});

function playSound() {
  var sound = new Audio('sound.mp3');
  sound.play();
}

setTimeout(function() {
  hoverTest('start');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you create a demo fiddle?

Comment: Updating with Fiddle now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy paste this in a file and run that html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #hover {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
    }
</style>
<div id="hover"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var interval = null;
var hoverTest = function(method){
    playSound();
    $("#hover").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    });

}
var playSound =function() {
    var sound = new Audio('http://www.sounddogs.com/previews/25/mp3/306470_SOUNDDOGS__an.mp3');
    sound.play();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    interval = setInterval('hoverTest()',3000);
    $("#hover").mouseenter(function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        interval = setInterval('hoverTest()',3000);
    })
})

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, i didnt realize you were using hover method. you need to use mouseenter and mouseleave method like this http://jsfiddle.net/uxbmu/10/

Comment: That still doesn't work. Enter and leave the red square a bunch - it will play the cat meow rapidly. And hover() is the same as mouseenter and mouseleave, to my knowledge. (Though I could be wrong.)

Comment: It works fine in my browser, if your checking jsfiddle then there is a problem in jsfiddle for hover and mouse enter and leaving events. you ve to click first on the preview area in the fiddle page and then try entering and leaving.

Comment: And yes the hover works same as mouseenter and mouseleave but i always find mouseenter and mouseleave less buggy and more accurate than hover. it can be my preference or i could be skeptical but i always find it better.

Comment: Yours still does not work for me in Firefox or Chrome on multiple machines, whether I'm following your directions on Fiddle or running them locally.

Comment: I have rewritten the code and used timeinterval instead of timeout function. its less messy and hope it works this time for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uxbmu/22/ - Still a no go, man. Sorry. Why are you using quotes around the function with setInterval? Not that removing them fixes it, but just curious.

Comment: The code i wrote wont work in jsfiddle coz jsfiddle loads all the js under onload function. i ll edit the answer again copy the whole thing in a html file and run that file in your browser. it should do it. and i m passing the function in quotes coz setInterval takes first param as a function. so if its a string it ll look for that function and adding "()" will execute that function. you can refer docs for it.

Comment: Its like using eval method where u can pass string and eval function will convert the string in to executable js.

Comment: Works, woohoo! I greatly appreciate all your effort. I'm still not entirely sure why my own code fails; I'm going to try playing around with it some more using your example and see if I can come up with something. I feel like loading parts outside document.ready() is the key, based on what you've shown me. Anyhow, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "clearTimeout(test);" the first thing in the hoverTest function.
eg:

```
var test;
function hoverTest(arg) {
  clearTimeout(test);
  if (arg == 'stop') {
    clearTimeout(test);
  }
  if (arg == 'start') {
    playSound();
    $('#hover').transition({
      opacity: 0,
      duration: 1000,
      complete: function() {
        $('#hover').transition({
          opacity: 1,
          duration: 1000,
          complete: function() {
            test = setTimeout(function() { hoverTest('start'); }, 3000);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (clear the timer before starting)

```
$('#hover').hover(function() {
  hoverTest('stop');
}, function() {
  clearTimeout(test);
  setTimeout(function() {
    hoverTest('start');
  }, 2000);
});
```